# Correct direction of flooring

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I am laying vinyl plank flooring in the kitchen.  I know the correct way is to go perpendicular to the house entrance and the floor joists. The trouble is the doorway to the living room. The living room is laid east to west, parallel to the floor joists and main entrance.  If I do it correctly the kitchen will be perpendicular to the living room hardwood floor and that might look odd. What should I do?

This question, although properly phrased and detailed has been put on hold by members of the community for some unknown reason. It calls for expertise and informed opinion, which seems to be lacking in some of the answers, which relied primarily on opinion rather than informed expertise.

I actually got a great answer from http://homeguides.sfgate.com/correct-direction-laying-hardwood-floors-49169.html

So yes there is actually a correct way to lay a floor.  Unfortunately this community board was utterly useless.

@mmathis you should spend more time educating your self as to home improvement techniques and less time gathering your friends to vote a question on hold. Although I admit it's a great way to force new users off the stack, if they disagree with your opinion.

Comment: `correct way is to go perpendicular to the house entrance and the floor joists` ..... that makes no sense .... you are talking about vinyl floor covering

Comment: @jsotola You’re thinking of sheet vinyl flooring. This is “vinyl plank”. It comes in 6” x 48” pieces.

Comment: @LeeSam yes you are correct it is 6x48" strips of flooring, vinyl made to look like wood

Comment: There is no "correct" way to lay flooring; it's all a matter of preference. VTC as off-topic decorating advice.

Comment: @mmathis I think I will take your advice, take a look and see which I prefer and go with that.  Thanks.

Comment: @diymama , i have vinyl plank in my kitchen. ... it is about 8mm thick ... please explain why you think that it has to be oriented a certain way ... is it a Feng Shui thing for you?

Comment: @jsotola LOL, no. :) It is a structural issue. Flooring (hardwood, laminate, vinyl plank) should be laid perpendicular to the floor joists for the most solid installation. Otherwise you risk it shifting and buckling over time. Also there is the design aspect to consider. Generally if the floor runs away from the main entrance, it gives the illusion of longer planks and thus a more elegant look.  I don't know about Feng Shui, you should consult an expert advice on that. :)

Comment: If you have a proper subfloor in place, joist direction is completely irrelevant. There should be no perceptible flex from foot traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you are correct, having two kinds of flooring that look like wood laid at right angle to each other could look odd.

However, having two different appearing wood floors could look odd too. If you can’t match the living room flooring EXACTLY, I’d choose a different style, color, texture, etc. of flooring in the kitchen.

The kitchen is a totally different use than the living room, which gives you an opportunity to change the flooring.

Often, when we design, we want to “define” each space separately. That is to say, we want to give each space it’s own character. Changing floor color, texture, etc. is one way to do that.

Consider a tile floor in the kitchen.

Comment: Thanks, yes the flooring is different, but works with the existing flooring, in terms of design.  That is not the concern. The problem is layout.  In terms of design, do I follow the wrong direction that is all over the house or do I install correctly but have a perpendicular transition? That's my dilema.